# Launch Tensorboard What-If Tool

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to use Tensorboard's new [What-If](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/tensorboard/plugins/interactive_inference) tool but don't understand how I launch or install the plugin.

I have followed the model and data steps outlined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/tensorboard/plugins/interactive_inference#what-do-i-need-to-use-it) and am stuck at the *"open this tool"* part.

I have the latest version of Tensorboard installed (`1.11.0`). Have cloned the Tensorboard repo and can successfully build and run the demo apps. When I launch Tensorboard, the interactive-inference plugin doesn't appear in the dashboard but there aren't any bazel `py_binary`'s to execute in the plugin repo to build from source.

I'm sure it's something small I'm missing, but can't find any docs online to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once inside the tensorboard repo, enter

```
bazel run //tensorboard -- --logdir /tmp/mylogs
```

with `/tmp/mylogs` being your log directory.

This will open a port for tensorboard with the what-if plugin which you can access via http://localhost:6006/#whatif

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run it on my local. I am using 1.12 tensorboard. 
./bazel-bin/tensorboard/tensorboard --logdir /path/to/your/model
Then go to: http://localhost:6006/ in the browser. Here you will have a dropdown, click on What-if Tool
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2zO3.png)